# C# open image path from listBox and show image in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listBox where I save paths from Images. We save the paths to sql Database. This works well. My question is, is there a way to click in `ListBox` on one of the paths and show the image in a `PictureBox`? Would be nice with a *mouse click event* in `ListBox`.

[image]

Comment: "Would be nice with a mouse click event in ListBox". Then do it with an mouse click event...? What is your current code?

Comment: Yes you can, this is your mission if you choose to accept it

Comment: @sLowDowN,

thanks for your answer. For this mouse click event i don't have a code.
I can explain to you what i've done. We load the path from Images to a SQL Server Database, then i create a SQL Statement to fill the ListBox with the path of the images (use a DataSet) (works fine). My problem is that i don't know the code for this event to click on a Item in my ListBox and open the image in a PictureBox. thanks

Comment: @ErnstSchrempfLordZwiebel If the answer helped you, you should mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on your ListBox and it should create you a new method.

Paste this code:

```
string path = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

EDIT:

Like Jimi said in the comments, the above code will lock the file.

Use this code instead:

```
using (Bitmap tmpBitmap = new Bitmap(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(tmpBitmap);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will lock the file. You should probably something like: `using (Bitmap tmpBitmap = new Bitmap(path)) { pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(tmpBitmap); };`