# can you tell me how to load image in pictureBox by clicking the file in listBox

Tags: c#

after uploading the pictures the filenames of the pictures will be shown in list Box i want to load the picture in picture Box every time i click the item in list Box but i don't how to do it. thanks for who want to help me. :)

this is the code:

```
public partial class fileee : UserControl
{
    Image<Bgr, byte> imgInput;
    Image<Gray, byte> CC;
    public fileee()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // browse file
    private void browse2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd1.Multiselect = true;
        ofd1.Filter = "Images|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;";
        if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string item in ofd1.SafeFileNames)
            {
                //textBox1.Text = ofd1.FileName;
                textBox2.Text = ofd1.SafeFileName;
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
                imgInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ofd1.FileName);
                pictureBox2.Image = imgInput.Bitmap;
            }   
        }
    }

    // selected index in listbox
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = curItem;

    }

    private void fileee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# open image path from listBox and show image in PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785895/c-sharp-open-image-path-from-listbox-and-show-image-in-picturebox)

Answer (score 0):

So, just on selectedintexChanged event type code:
`picturebox.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(listbox.SelectedItem.ToString()/*only if your item is a path,if not then enter your path*/), picturebox.Size);`
That should be it